# How do I stop Knockout from clearing the checkboxes?

Tags: knockout.js

How do I stop Knockout from clearing the checkboxes?

https://jsfiddle.net/mezv2tns/

```
var vm = {
    state: ko.observable({
        'success': true,   
        'items': [{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'def'}]
    }),
    items: ko.observableArray([{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'def'}]),

    itemsMapping: ko.observableArray([{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'def'}]),
};

$(function() {

    console.log('go');

    ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#a')[0]); 

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log('update');
        // Imagine this is coming from an Ajax request.
        var dataFromServer = [{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'def'}, {'name': 'new'}];
        var stateFromServer = {'success': true, 'items': dataFromServer};

        // Update the observables using different techniques.
        vm.state(stateFromServer);
        vm.items(dataFromServer);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(dataFromServer, {}, vm.itemsMapping);
    }, 1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: state().items">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want the constant updates from the server to update the table but the checkboxes should be independent of that; I don't want to send the checkbox state to the server and then have it merge it with the updates.

Comment: That template will rerender the table whenever `state` updates. You'll need to restructure the template so that the table's `foreach` binding can access the `items` observable array without going through `state` or any other observable that updates. Better yet, store the checkbox values in your view-model somewhere. Knockout expects that the state of your application is maintained in view-models, not in the DOM.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, even isolating items as an observable array doesn't stop the checkboxes from being unchecked.

Comment: How do I store the state of the checkboxes in the view model without syncing it with the server where the rest of the data comes from?

Comment: How you store state in your view-model depends on how the items are keyed and on how long you want to keep the information about what's checked.

Comment: The easiest thing is to create a view-model for each item and cache these in a plain JS object keyed on the item's name. Then, you can render against a computed array of view-models, which you derive by combining information from the `items` array and this cache. With this approach, you would create a new view model on a cache miss. But when would you clean up the cache? Storing it on `vm` seems the most sensible choice.

Comment: Also, if you're only supporting modern browsers, `Map` works better than a plain JS object for this type of caching.

Comment: If this seems overly complicated, that's a result of breaking from assumptions that Knockout builds on. Knockout assumes that we would usually bind that checkbox to some boolean value on a view-model. If you want to keep two separate states for each item, you'll have two separate objects for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkboxes aren't being cleared, they're being redrawn. You use a `foreach` binding to generate them according to what you have in your observableArrays. Each "server fetch" replaces the data in the arrays, so you get new boxes.

If you want the items that are drawn to persist, you'll have to do something other than throwing away and replacing all the data. For example, when new data comes in, you delete only items that are no longer represented, and add any that are new.

```js
var initialData = [{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'def'}];
var vm = {
    state: ko.observable({
        'success': true,   
        'items': initialData
    }),
    items: ko.observableArray(initialData),
    
    itemsMapping: ko.observableArray(initialData),
    persistentItems: ko.observableArray(initialData)
};

function updatePersistent(newData) {
    // Delete any that are not in newData (not implemented)

    // Add any that are not already here
    for (var i=0; i<newData.length; ++i) {
        if (!found(newData[i])) vm.persistentItems.push(newData[i]);
    }
}

function found(item) {
    var items = vm.persistentItems();
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; ++i) {
       if (items[i].name == item.name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
   
$(function() {
    
    console.log('go');
 
 ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#a')[0]);
    
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log('update');
        // Imagine this is coming from an Ajax request.
        var dataFromServer = [{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'def'}, {'name': 'new'}];
        var stateFromServer = {'success': true, 'items': dataFromServer};
        
        // Update the observables using different techniques.
        vm.state(stateFromServer);
        vm.items(dataFromServer);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(dataFromServer, {}, vm.itemsMapping);
        updatePersistent(dataFromServer);
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px;
    height: 50px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
      <h1>Desired Technique</h1>
<table data-bind="foreach: state().items">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td></tr>
</table>
<hr>
    <h1>Technique 2</h1>
<table data-bind="foreach: items()">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td></tr>
</table>
<hr>
    <h1>Technique 3</h1>
<table data-bind="foreach: itemsMapping()">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td></tr>
</table>
    <h1>Persistent</h1>
<table data-bind="foreach: persistentItems">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td></tr>
</table>
    
</div>
```